# Problems with relative pronouns

Tags: pronombres

> Hoy es el día que haré que se enamore de mí.

Here I literally can't understand a thing. Why there are two “que”?

hoy - today
es - is
el día - the day
que - that
haré - I will
que se enamore de mí: - ??

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: From personal experience "hacer" is one of the weird verbs where the future tense is irregular

Comment: Actually, *haré* means *I will make*.

Answer (score 5):

One way to understand the whole sentence is by adding all the parts:

> Hoy es el día **que yo haré que** (ella/él) se enamore de mí

- Today is the day that (I will) make that (she/he) fall in love with me

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speak by any means, but the statement causing confusion ...

> que se enamore de mí

... is a reflexive verb, where the action can be applied to oneself and here **se** is for he/she. For example, if I fall in love, I'm "applying" an action/feeling to myself. This class of verb is suffixed with **se**, hence [enamorarse](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=enamorarse). Google might mistake it for the irregular form of the infinitive "saber" (but that is sé not se). The verb can be used as both reflexive (to fall in love) and standard (to romantically love).

> enamorarse de mí

Is another way of writing this, but it doesn't seem to be used often. Well enamorarse isn't used often, but preocuparse is very common. The verb enamorarse must a have *verb + de* and prevents the following from being correct.

> se enamore conmigo

The above is naturally how I'd write this, but its wrong.

Comment: Emm no, la construcción ‘se enamore conmigo’ también es correcta. ¿De dónde sacaste que ‘de’ tiene que seguir al verbo reflexivo?

Comment: Thanks, its here https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=enamorarse

Comment: Ah eso sí. Gramaticalmente hablando, el ‘de’ hace que ‘enamorarse’ , siendo un verbo reflexivo, se lo asocie a un complemento (‘de mí’). Gramaticalmente, si no se usa el ‘se’ la frase podría interpretarse como ‘que se enamore bajo mi prescencia, pero no específicamente de mí’. Sin embargo, en la práctica y con el debido contexto, tu última construcción se considera equivalente a las anteriores; ya que es la única forma de que cobre sentido

Comment: Thank you @tac this is very useful to know. Now understand. Gracias, esto es muy util para saber. Ahora entiendo y mi error está un poco divertido.